# How can I travel directory which is named with guid?

Tags: perl, path, guid

Today, I have written a perl script, as the following code:

```
my @files = <./{FF35B8A6-985C-4644-87B1-3FE83D1A50B}/*>;
print @files;
```

But it outputs nothing. When I changed the guid path with general path such as d:, it worked. Why? Could perl support the path named with guid string?

OS: Windows 7 32bit
Perl version: ActivePerl 5.12.3

Comment: @Blagovest Actually it lists files. All the files matching the glob. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my @files = <\\{FF35B8A6-985C-4644-87B1-3FE83D1A50B\\}/*>;
print @files;
```

should work. You need to quote special characters (here `{` and  `}`).

Quote from File::Glob

> On DOSISH systems, backslash is a valid directory separator character. In this case, use of backslash as a quoting character (via GLOB_QUOTE) interferes with the use of backslash as a directory separator. The best (simplest, most portable) solution is to use forward slashes for directory separators, and backslashes for quoting. However, this does not match "normal practice" on these systems. As a concession to user expectation, therefore, backslashes (under GLOB_QUOTE) only quote the glob metacharacters '[', ']', '{', '}', '-', '~', and backslash itself. All other backslashes are passed through unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the glob:

```
opendir my $fh, '.' or die $!; 
my @files = grep { -d } readdir $fh;
print @files;
```

I prefer the more pure perl versions to the globs, because globs do not (to me) feel as strict as perl naturals. As has been pointed out in another answer, glob uses other metacharacters.

Comment: +1 Good 'ol `opendir/readdir/closedir` when you don't want to work around the magic of `glob` and. `<>`

Comment: @TLP It 'd better filter dot directories.

Comment: @thinkhy It filters nothing, in it's current form. This is no glob, with willy-nilly behaviour, it does exactly what you tell it to, nothing else. You wanna filter "dot directories", you do `@files = grep !/^\./, @files`

Comment: @TLP I do "my @files = grep { -d and $_ ne "." and $_ ne ".." } readdir $fh" im my code.

Comment: @thinkhy That'll also bring along hidden dirs, such as `.foo`, though.

Comment: It dosen't matter.At present, I just developed in Windows.